# Verify Android user is human (without a CAPTCHA)

Tags: android, captcha, bots, spam, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app where users can add ratings, and I don't want them to have to register to do it, but I also don't want it to be easy for bots to game the ratings.

Is there a way I can be reasonably (doesn't have to be 100%, but I don't want to use reactive heuristic methods) sure that my users are human? *Without* requiring any kind of CAPTCHA / sign-in / other action. Normally I would say that this is impossible, but since my app runs on Android I think we can do better than nothing.

## Gmail address.

My first thought was to get their gmail address from `AccountManager`, but I can't see a way to verify that they own that email address - i.e. a bot could just send made-up emails to my server, so I don't think this can work (and I don't want to make them authenticate my app using their google account; they are unlikely to do this).

## GCM

My next thought was to use Google's Cloud Messaging thing. I can get a cloud messaging ID from the device, send it to my server, send a random cloud message from the server back to the device, and send that message back to the server. I *think* this at least verifies that they do have an Android device with a gmail account, which is good enough.

## SMS

Of course I could send them an SMS, but that costs money and to be seamless means that I need to have permission to read their messages, which I'd really like to avoid (especially as the rating is an optional feature).

## Android Licensing Server

Maybe it is possible to use the [Licensing Verification Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/overview.html) to get a signed assurance from Google that the user downloaded it from the market, but due to the nature of my app I can't put it in the market.

## Device ID, EMEI, phone number, etc.

Of course I can't use these. Bots could just make them up!

So GCM looks like the best (and only) option. Can anyone think of anything else?

Comment: put a private key in you apk, download from you server a random text, send it back ciphered, you'll know it comes from your apk. your GCM though probably works, too

Comment: If a bot could get hold of the private key from the decompiled APK, it's the same.

Comment: Ah I like the private key idea. Obviously it can be hacked with enough effort, but I could make it difficult.

Comment: I think this may hold the answer! It's only just been released though: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Show some popups randomly and place their close buttons at different place, so user has to close them.

OR

Using drag drop API ask user to drag and drop button into some area on screen and then submit rating. You can randomize placing of button.

There could be multiplaces where you can drag button but you can instruct user to put in the right one.

Comment: Sounds like a lame version of a traditional CAPTCHA. I'm trying to avoid user-input.

Comment: I don't think the OP is worried about a bot automating his Android app to send bogus reviews.  I think he's worried about a bot running on a PC that HTTP posts reviews to his server, pretending that it was sent from his app.

Answer (score 0):

As you control both sides of the communication, you could do something like this:

### Flow

1. App: Request one-time secret token from server.
2. Server: Create one-time secret token and a tracking-id and send both to the App, while keeping track of the secret token by using the tracking-id.
3. App: encrypt the voting using the one-time secret token (see below about encryption)
4. App: send encrypted message and tracking-id to server.
5. Server: Find secret token using tracking-id, make sure it hasn't been already used and decrypt the voting using the secret-token.

### Encryption

You can use any symetrical encryption technology. A very simple example would be to XOR your message (i.e. voting) with the secret-token on the App-side. On Server-side XOR-ing again with the same secret-token gives the plain message again.

This method is safe as long as your method of encryption is not known to the attacker. If it is known of course he can just simulate the requests the App does, but it would hold true for every method, so you probably should use something better than simple XOR-ing.

Comment: Actually it doesn't require a human, but it does require your App. As explained it cannot be faked by a Bot/Script sending requests directly to your server.

Comment: Ah, so the same as njzk2's suggestion. Pretty much just "Sign the requests with a secret key contained in the app.". I don't think anything else adds any security.

Comment: It adds security as the secret key is not included in the App, so decompilation of the APK would not reveal it. And by using one-time tokens you can avoid multiple votings by the same person - if that's a concern.

Comment: No, essentially your scheme is "the app contains a secret". Your secret is the algorithm, and njzk2's is a key, but there's essentially no difference between those from a security point of view.